# Get user info from google plus using php

Tags: php, google-plus

How do I get user info like profile picture, location, description etc.
I have a field in form called google+ url. Now If any user filled it with their google+ url, I want to get their profile picture, location and description using their google+ url, Is it possible without creating google+ application?

Comment: IMO Yes, but you have to parse the HTML code.

Comment: As @YogeshSuthar states it is *might* probably possible by parsing their profile page, but it would be so much nicer to just use oauth to get the wanted information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google+ URL generally contains the Google+ ID for a user. You can parse out that ID, and then make a people.get API call using the ID. The response will only contain information that is publicly available on the user's profile, though. Also, if a user is verified, their URL will not contain their ID, but rather their verified name, but this will also work as an ID.

In PHP, the call looks like: `$me = $plus->people->get('{{ID}}');`

You can learn more about the people.get API call and see a full example at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get.

Comment: Actually the possibility to use custom names in the API has been added quite a while ago (https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=359) :)

So things like $plus->people->get('+GooglePlusDevelopers') will work as well :)